# Does the IR Blaster on an Android phone receive as well as send?

Tags: device-firmware

Is the IR Blaster communication two-way or only one-way? I have seen many remote control apps for my Android phone but none that learn from an existing remote.

Comment: Well there is a tripod that supposedly uses infrared to control the samsung GS5 camera, so I guess that would not work, right?

Answer (score 1):

***`For transmitting, a single Infrared LED and resistor are needed. For receiving, an IR receiver module with internal bandpass filter is needed.`***

There are remotes that will send and receive. Universal remotes will sometimes have a "learning mode" to mimic another remote.  An example of this at the bottom of my answer.

**But a receiving IR isn't a standard feature on Android devices**, as of this answer I haven't heard of or have found any online of that can. But with a PC program and Android app you can mimic remotes. The link below is one such program.

[Unified Remote](http://www.unifiedremote.com/features). There is a free version and a paid version with more features.

The link is just for the feature list of the app. There is a server (PC) side as well as Android side.The amount of remotes that you can map over to your device is staggering, I think you can even design your own remotes. By using one of the remote templates, your device is effectively "learning/receiving" the other remotes codes (you don't even have to have another remote physically there). You would still be accomplishing your goal.

---

**example**

*I had a Yamaha Natural Sound home theater receiver and the remote had a **"Learn Mode"**. So you switch it to learn, place the "other" remote in front of it. Press the button on "other" remote, then press a button on the Yamaha remote that you want that command mapped to. You now have control of the other devices functions. You can also clear mapped button commands and enter new ones as needed.*

Comment: But the IR Blaster on a phone is send only? I like the idea of a remote control on my phone but none of them seem very good so far. If it could learn it would be a better way to completely replace the remote.

Comment: Read the features on the link that I posted in my answer.

Comment: Please answer "yes" or "no" and only use links to confirm what you wrote here. What happens if your link goes dead? Does the IR Blaster on an Android phone receive? I had a look but I couldn't find anything about the Android version learning, only the PC version.

Comment: As a standard feature NO you can't receive a signal from the IR . What happens when the link I posted goes dead, well that's just life. I don't control the actions of others. The link was just for feature list of the app. There is a server (PC) side as well. The amount of remotes that you can map over to your device is staggering, I think you can even design your own remotes. By using one of the remote templates, your device is effectively "learning/receiving" the other remotes codes (you don't even have to have another remote physically there). You would still be accomplishing your goal.

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that if your answer relies on information from a link (i.e. the reader has to click on the link to fully understand the answer) and the link goes dead, the answer is no longer helpful. Someone may read this question in five years time and all the relevant information should be on this page. I'm on several SE sites and people always ask that answers that rely heavily on links be edited to contain the information in the page. If you put the information from your comment into an answer I will accept it. Currently, your answer does not answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

My Honor 8 pro both sends and receives infrared signals. Its remote control app has learn feature and a special app(I don't remember the name) allows me to connect to old Nokia devices via infrared to transfer files.

Comment: LG Phones also come with a quick remote app to learn.